# Facebook like camera roll android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-camera, android-gallery

I need to be able to open camera roll like facebook and customize the header

- when press gallery button, open camera roll with all image in all folder without categories or album
- enable to customize the header
- enable to open camera and take picture.

can any one tell me how to do this, i have searched and all result opening the chooser and then i select the gallery and them find albums and so on..

[image]

Comment: You have to write a Gallery like Activity/s with ActionBar, to display all images you have.

Comment: @JafarKhQ : do you know any good example that will work with this and compatible with many devices?

Comment: Nope, search for an open-source gallery or check the android stock gallery app source code.